# Another case of "Be extra careful with `auto` in the Eigen library."

Tags: c++, eigen, lto

EDIT: The title was

> How do eigen expressions and link-time-optimization interact

But this issue has nothing to do with lto.

I just introduced and then fixed the following bug:

```
Eigen::Vector4d some_function(double arg) {

Eigen::Matrix4d mat;
mat << 2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,2,13,14,15,16;
    Eigen::Vector4d spline_constraints(a(arg),b(arg),c,d);
       
    auto coefficients =  mat.lu().solve(spline_constraints);
    return coefficients;

}
```

This is pseudocode. In actuality both the function and the matrix are static members of a class and `a(double arg)` and `b(double arg)` are also static member functions.
I hope it is suffcient. If not, I will try to cook up a minimal working example.

The behaviour is very compiler dependent:

#### GCC

When I compile it into a static library and link the library elsewhere, it SEEMS to work fine, regardless of debug build or release build (i.e. with non-lto optimizations).

If I compile and link it with link time optimization, it compiles and links fine and the runtime behaves in a wrong way:
With gcc a sparse matrix of size 1350x1350, whose construction depends on the code above is claimed to be non-decomposible with the lu decomposition (without lto it doesn't claim so, although I'm not sure, the decomposition is correct in that case).

#### Clang

In release build with or without lto I get a segmentation fault.
The debug build works fine.

#### Fix

The code is fixed by with one of the following:

```
Eigen::Vector4d some_function() {

Eigen::Matrix4d mat;
mat << 2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,2,13,14,15,16;
    Eigen::Vector4d spline_constraints(a,b,c,d);
       
    auto coefficients =  mat.lu().solve(spline_constraints).eval();
    return coefficients;

}
```

that is by adding `.eval()`
or

```
Eigen::Vector4d some_function() {

Eigen::Matrix4d mat;
mat << 2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,2,13,14,15,16;
    Eigen::Vector4d spline_constraints(a,b,c,d);
       
    return mat.lu().solve(spline_constraints);
}
```

that is, by returning the expression itself.

My question is: What exactly happened here?

Related (would be nice to know, not really part of the question): Is there a compiler warning or other feature that could prevent me from making this mistake in the future?
Also (likewise): Is there some part of the Eigen docs, that would have warned me of this, had I found it before?

My impression from the docs was, that failing to add `.eval()` somewhere could result in decreased performance but not in undefined behaviour.
EDIT: I was wrong: The docs state that wrong application of `eval()` can lead to segfaults:
[Eigen docs on eval()](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html#TopicPitfalls_auto_keyword)

Comment: I think the line `mat << 2,2,3,4;5,6,7,8;9,10,11,2;13,14,15,16;` wrongly contains semi-colons. I think the first expression will be `mat << 2,2,3,4;` and the 3 others will be useless instructions without any visible effects.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I copied it over from octave to get a fake matrix that is actually invertible.
In the actual code there are other numbers which also lead to a invertible matrix.
Fixed this here, thanks!

Comment: My guess would be that `.lu()` returns a temporary and `.solve()` saves a reference to that temporary, so not calling `.eval()` and saving the result in a variable invalidates that reference.

Comment: So the `.lu()` temporary goes out of scope after the line and hence I return a stale reference?

Comment: Oh, now I get it. It has nothing to do with lto. Its just that the `.eval()` heals the iladvised use of auto in the beginning of the line and it was shear luck/bad luck that this all worked with this or that compiler setting. Well thanks. If you post this as an answer, I will mark it correct.